# Nesting tables between rows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So, I've got the prove of concept down however I feel like I'm doing it in a very round-about way. Is there an easier way to accomplish what I am doing with my collapsing tables?

[Here's a JSFiddle using my code.](https://jsfiddle.net/KonradWright95/3n2j218x/)

Right now, I'm making each row a separate table to put tables in between my rows. Like so.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</td>
    <th>Col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#collapse-div-1">Cell 1</a></td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="collapse-div-1">
  <table>...</table>
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: collapsed table]
[image: revealed table]

Comment: Looks fine to me. What specifically is bothering you?

Comment: Well, each table columns are not synced up on their widths. So if you replace once Cell's data with 'asdf'*100 then things start looking a little weird. Also they all look slightly disjointed.

Comment: @showdev an easy problem to locate is by simply resizing the JSFiddle window. The header becomes disconnected to the actual table.

Comment: @KonradWright "The header becomes disconnected to the actual table" its because of `margin-bottom` to the table at that screen width